# Getting 'Undefined error in httr call' when using remDr$navigate with R Selenium - how to fix it?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rselenium

remDr$navigate (url) error: Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

This happens for URL
`url <- "https://eprel.ec.europa.eu/screen/product/airconditioners"` 
Remote driver is configured without errors. What could be the cause and how to solve it? Is it perhaps that this website is not scrape-able?

I tried checking:

- the specification of URL (it's correct)
- using get() and navigateTo functions.

My system is 64-bit, and so is R, but the only available versions for webdriver for Chrome and Firefox are 32-bit. Could that be the problem?

The ChatGPT says *it could be related to the RSelenium setup or compatibility with the specific website*.
Could it be that for this website, another scraping tool/package should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://eprel.ec.europa.eu/api/products/airconditioners?_page=1&_limit=25&indoorSoundPowerCoolingMin=1&indoorSoundPowerCoolingMax=99&outdoorSoundPowerCoolingMin=0&outdoorSoundPowerCoolingMax=99&indoorSoundPowerHeatingMin=1&indoorSoundPowerHeatingMax=99&outdoorSoundPowerHeatingMin=0&outdoorSoundPowerHeatingMax=99&coolingDesignLoadMin=0.1&coolingDesignLoadMax=99.9&heatingDesignLoadMin=0.1&heatingDesignLoadMax=99.9&sort0=onMarketStartDateTS&order0=DESC&sort1=energyClass&order1=DESC" %>%
  request() %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE, check_type = FALSE) %>%
  pluck("hits")
```